# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel to third party after upgrading to TLS 1.2

Tags: web-services, tls1.2

I am getting the following exception after upgrading our server to TLS 1.2

"System.Net.WebException: **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel**.\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)\r\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at

Any idea to resolve the issue?

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
the above lines are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are meant to know the currently active protocol your https support. Confirm your SSL supported protocol [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Click on the link in the search result you will get a page that looks like what you can see in the screenshot below. That will determine the protocol to specify in your code.

[image]